# how $x= \cos\theta$ and $y= \sin\theta$?

Tags: trigonometry

I'm learning Trigonometry right now and at current about trigonometry functions. I'm little bit confused right now in a section of the chapter. Please have a look at the image. [image: Image 1]

I didn't get the second paragraph .How $x= \cos \theta$ and $y = \sin \theta$? Can we name the sides of the triangle with same name as of coordinate sides like in the figure the triangle is having x and y value? 

**EDIT**- I also want to know why radius of the circle is taken unity and not more than that. For example - 2 or 3 or 4. There will be any difference or the conclusion will be same?

Comment: On the axis "$x'x$", the coordinate is $x$.Is it what is annoying you, that $x$ appears twice? If so, it's not really a problem. Anyway, you can call the axis $(O,\vec i)$ if you wish, with a unit vector $\vec i$. Here $x$ and $y$ are the coordinates of $P$.

Comment: I wanted to know that is there any kind of relation between the both x and both y since they are used in two places.

Comment: The relevant places are in $P(x,y)$, and on segments on the axes, showing where abscissa $x$ of $P$ is measured, and where ordinate $y$ of $P$ is measured (it's on a parallel to the $y'y$ axis, but it's not wrong, it could be anywhere actually). These are the *same* $x$ and $y$. However, there is a third $x$ on the drawing, that is not really relevant and may be replaced with something more clear (unit vectors, here $\vec{OA}$ and $\vec{OB}$): this $x$ is here only to show the $x'x$ axis, and likewise a third $y$ to show the $y'y$ axis.

Comment: I've edited the question. Please answer

Comment: Already answered by others below. You may also see this as an [homothetic transofmration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homothetic_transformation)

Comment: hint: how long is the hypotenuse in $\Delta POM$?

Answer (score 2):

$$x=r\cos\theta$$
the radius  here is $r=1$
$$x=\cos\theta$$
$$y=r\sin\theta$$
$$y=\sin\theta$$

Comment: I've edited the question. Please answer.

Answer (score 1):

It is just the definition of cosinus and sinus of a real number.
Let $\theta\in\mathbb{R}$. Then $\cos \theta$ and $\sin \theta$ are defined as the abscissa and the ordinate of the point $P$ of the unit circle such that $\angle AOP = \theta$ (oriented angle).

Comment: I've edited the question. Please answer.

Comment: @user3788135: if $P(x,y)$ were on the circle of radius $r>0$, then we would have $x = r \cos \theta$ and $y = r\sin \theta$.